# If rows match on two conditions, subtract in particular order, Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to write Tidyverse code that finds two rows that have exactly matching values on two conditions. The rows should match on Participant_ID & Indicator. There should be no more than two rows that match exactly on these two values. In this pair of matches, one will have occurred at timepoint 1 and the other at timepoint 4. After the matches are identified, I want the score at timepoint 4 to be subtracted from the score at timepoint 1. I would also like to preserve the Group number in the final tibble.

There will be rows that don't have matches. Those can be omitted, if possible. I don't want them in the  resulting tibble.

I am having trouble wrapping my head around this, so thank you very much for your help!

```
example <- tibble (
  Participant_ID = c('Part1','Part2','Part1','Part2','Part1','Part2','Part1','Part2'),
  Indicator =c('item1','item1','item1','item1','item2','item2','item2','item2'),
  Timepoint = c(1,1,4,4,1,1,4,4),
  Score = c(3,3,1.5,3,4,4,3.5,3.5),
Group = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
example %>%
  pivot_wider(c(Participant_ID, Indicator, Group), names_from = Timepoint, values_from = Score) %>%
  transmute(Participant_ID, Indicator, Group, Score = `1` - `4`)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#   Participant_ID Indicator Group Score
#   <chr>          <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Part1          item1         1   1.5
# 2 Part2          item1         2   0  
# 3 Part1          item2         1   0.5
# 4 Part2          item2         2   0.5
```

---

Data

```r
example <- structure(list(Participant_ID = c("Part1", "Part2", "Part1", "Part2", "Part1", "Part2", "Part1", "Part2"), Indicator = c("item1", "item1", "item1", "item1", "item2", "item2", "item2", "item2"), Timepoint = c(1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4), Score = c(3, 3, 1.5, 3, 4, 4, 3.5, 3.5), Group = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: If there was a variable in the original tibble that I just want to preserve (it'll be consistent on both matching rows), how would I bring it down into the final tibble? Thank you!

Comment: Use `mutate` instead of `transmute`. You may also need to add it as an `id_cols` (first arg of `pivot_wider`. It might get complicated, perhaps that should be in your sample data.

Comment: I added it. Sorry. I thought that part would be simple. Thank you for your help!

Comment: See my edit, I think the pattern should make sense.

Comment: It does. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

One `tidyverse` approach is to use use `pivot_wider()` in `tidyr` to place the matches matches into one row, then calculate the difference between the two scores:

```
example %>% 
    pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Participant_ID, Indicator), values_from = Score, names_from = Timepoint, names_prefix = "Score_Timepoint_") %>%
    mutate(Score_difference = Score_Timepoint_1 - Score_Timepoint_4)
```

This produces:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Participant_ID Indicator Score_Timepoint_1 Score_Timepoint_4 Score_difference
  <chr>          <chr>                 <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>
1 Part1          item1                     3               1.5              1.5
2 Part2          item1                     3               3                0  
3 Part1          item2                     4               3.5              0.5
4 Part2          item2                     4               3.5              0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `arrange` the data by descending `Timepoint` and then use `diff` by group.

```
library(dplyr)

example %>%
  arrange(Participant_ID, Indicator, desc(Timepoint)) %>%
  group_by(Participant_ID, Indicator) %>%
  summarise(Score = diff(Score))

# Participant_ID Indicator Score
#  <chr>          <chr>     <dbl>
#1 Part1          item1       1.5
#2 Part1          item2       0.5
#3 Part2          item1       0  
#4 Part2          item2       0.5
```